# Kotlin- not getting the value of params from either.eager block

Tags: kotlin, gson

I wonder how can I create a new jsonObject from overwriting some key values on existing object. In my case I have one jsonObject `existingData`, and an `order` of type Map<String, Any>.

```
// order is of type Map<String, Any?>
val keys = listOf("service", "customerContact", "deliveryAddress", "deliveryZipCode", "deliveryZipArea", "deliveryCountryCode", "deliveryPhoneNumber")
val newObject = existingData
  .toMap()
  .foldLeft(jsonObject()) { acc, entry ->
    if (relevantKeys.contains(entry.key)
        && !matching(entry.value, order.get(entry.key))
    ) acc.set(entry.key, order?.get(entry.key).toString())
    else acc.set(entry.key, entry.value.asString)
  }
```

So, here I need to check if the `keys` list contains a key on a jsonObject and if the value for that key on the object is different from the value of the `order` Map entry. If they are not matching the key on the object should be updated with the value from the order Map. How can I do this, in js I would use reduce, but I am not that familiar with kotlin, and since we can't use fold on JsonObject, I wonder how can I do something like this?

Comment: existingData is of type JsonObject from gson library.

Comment: Ah okay, so you're using gson. That makes a big difference.

Comment: @Sweeper I have updated my question with a new attempt, but unfortunately I get a compile error for this, but that would be the logic, I just don't know how to do it in the right kotlin way to set the keys on an empty JsonObject

Comment: If a key is in `keys` but not in `existingData`, do you want to add the key into the new object?

Comment: yes, I would add that key, even though that shouldn't be the case, since I have only listed keys that will always be in the existingData

Comment: What is the compiler error that you get?

Comment: Type mismatch.Required:JsonObject Found:Unit for lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want this:

```
val newObject = existingData.deepCopy().apply {
    for (key in relevantKeys) {
        add(key, Gson().toJsonTree(order[key]))
    }
}
```

`add` will overwrite the old value if the key already exists. `toJsonTree` converts the `Any?` to a `JsonElement`. This is assuming that the things inside inside `order` can be converted to JSON without any more type information.